# How I can prevent moveend from locking out the map caused by api call

Tags: javascript, leaflet, vuejs2

I have a map that only display the markers according to the map current coordinates and we get the markers positions through external API

```
  moveEnd (e) {
        // console.log(e.target)

    const map = this.$refs.map.mapObject
    const bound = map.getBounds()
    const minx = bound.getWest()
    const maxx = bound.getEast()
    const miny = bound.getSouth()
    const maxy = bound.getNorth()
    const zoom = map.getZoom()
    let cat = 2
    console.log(zoom)
    if (zoom <= 2) cat = 1
    else if (zoom >= 4) cat = 3

    const queryString = `?maxx=${maxx}&minx=${minx}&maxy=${maxy}&miny=${miny}&cat=${cat}`

 this.fetchPortsOnMap(queryString)
  }
```

fetchPortsOnMap is function that gets the markers using Axios.

the issue that map freeze/hang during the api call because it is waiting for the function response, what I want is to prevent map from freezing and ignore whether there response or not.

And here is my fetchPortsOnMap function

```
  fetchPortsOnMap (queryString) {
        this.loadingFunc = true
        httpAuth().get('ports' + queryString)
          .then((response) => {
            this.loadingFunc = false
            this.ports = response.data
          })
      },
```

Comment: can you post your fetchPortsOnMap function ?

Comment: @AlexParij I have added my function, loadingFunc is just flag that I used to prevent function to be called again while it still fetching

Comment: why would you think the map is waiting for the function response. Looks like regular async call me. The only place where I see that it can freeze the map is when loading new data from the response ``this.ports = response.data```

Comment: because map freeze when response is pending and unfreeze when it gets a response, I decided to test my theory by making api call only to happen once  as I thought may be markers might be the issue (less than 300 markers on display at a time) and found map is working just fine